# How to handle .Net ClickOnce system specific settings

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

**Background:** 
I have an application that will be installed on several different machines. The application obtains system specific settings from a settings.xml file that it reads in when the program starts. Of course, each iteration has a different settings file, and will not function correctly if it has a different system's settings file.

Currently, I have the settings file without any of the fields filled out. Each time I publish a new version to the server, that the machines will update to the next time they launch, it copies over the blank settings file. 
Obviously, this is not desired behavior.

**Question/Issue:** How can I correctly manage these settings files? I want the blank settings file to be moved with the initial deployment, but then ignored on the updates.

**Possible Solution:** I'm reading through the tutorials on MSDN about OneClick applications but I can't seem to find anything on including a data file for the installation but not when the updates are published.

I have been messing around with the Custom Actions of my installer
 [image: Custom Actions]

However; When I add a settings file in the 'Install' folder it automatically is included in the 'Commit' folder as well.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the properties on this file for Build Action and Copy to Output Directory? There is one setting where the file won't copy if the source file is older.

Comment: The Build Action is 'Content' and I just changed Copy to Output Directory from 'Copy Always' to' Copy if newer'. But isn't this changing the behavior of how I am publishing TO my server, while instead I want to change the behavior of the application as it pulls the update FROM my server?